# File is not getting delivered in subpackage in spec file

Tags: rpm, specifications

I am having an spec file which has 3 subpackages inside it. Each generating separate rpm.
But I am not able to use "install -m0644 source/location/file target/location/file" inside subpackage. Is there any flag that can refer that this install is for that specific package or will go into that rpm only.

Fog e.g
package A
install file file2

package B
install file4 file5

Comment: Summary: %package XXX  %description XXX  %package YYY  %description YYY

Comment: What *specifically* is the problem you are having? The files aren't going to the correct package? How many `%files` sections do you have?

Comment: The problem I am facing is that in one of the subpackages I am trying to deploy a file from one location to other location. And RPM is getting generated but while installing the RPM getting error: 1) "install: cannot stat `/location of file/file': No such file or directory".     2)/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.xsF0ip: line 1: /destination/file: No such file or directory.         I have added %files for all the subpackages including the MAIN package. One more doubt what should go into %file mySubPackage ???

Comment: You are getting an error when you are *installing* the rpm on the target system? Why are you using `install` at that point (in `%post`?)? Do the target file and destination directory both exist at that point? You won't have access to unpackaged source files during `%pre` or `%post`.

Comment: Yes I am getting an error during installation of the rpm on the target. Could you suggest a way I can achieve deployment of a shell script through an RPM generated out of subpackage.That can be installed seprately too. {"install -m0755 /existing/directory/file.sh /target_machine/directory_created_by_other_RPM/file.sh"}. Destination file is present but destination directory is created by other RPM which must be installed before this one.

Comment: You can have the sub-package own only the file (and not the directory) but RPM will create the directory to install it into if forced I believed (you can require the main package in the sub-package to make doing that require `--force` though). Installing the file should be done normally. You "install" it into the buildroot during `%install` and list it in `%files` for the sub-package and just let RPM take care of it.

Comment: Thanks Etan For your patience and helping me out. I got the solution I copied shell script to temporary directory under the Main package. And then I deployed it to the target machine.

Comment: I don't think I understand that (and it sounds odd) but ok.